# Laravel - Can't send email with sendmail driver

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, sendmail.exe

I have an application that send several emails using the smtp driver. But at some point, and I don't know why, some domains stop receiving email from application.

So, I change the driver to `sendmail` and change the sent email.

In my mac works fine but when I try to pass it to a windows server I have to change the config sendmail path and returns me an error.

In my `app/config.php` I change driver `smtp` to `sendmail` and sendmail path to `'sendmail' => '\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t',` .
Next I go to php.ini and add this:

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and in `.env` I also change the driver name.

Now I have this error and I don't understand why:

```
Process could not be started ['\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Anyone can help me with that?
First I don't understand why people received email and now don't.
and how can resolve this error.

Thank you

Comment: Try changing your single slashes double-slashes, except for the one next to the double quotes, since it's escaping the letter in front of it. `"\"C:\\xampp\\sendmail\\sendmail.exe\" -t"`

Comment: thank you for you answer @aynber . Now the error change to this 'Process could not be started ['C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t -f"no-reply@mail.pt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'